# How do I use Pandas to interpolate on the first few rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, interpolation

I've got some astrophysics data with unfilled rows, which I'm trying to use the Pandas Interpolate method to fill. It works on the np.NaN values found everywhere except in the first three rows. It fills the values, but instead of being a linear fill, it just places in the values of the fourth row. The first chunk of the dataframe (called avgdf_final) looks like this:

```
        day     lon     lat    rad
nums                              
0     319.0     NaN     NaN    NaN
1     320.0     NaN     NaN    NaN
2     321.0     NaN     NaN    NaN
3     322.0  56.485  2.7800  1.158
4     323.0  43.300  2.6800  1.166
5     324.0  30.100  2.5775  1.174
```

I've tried this (with like a million different minor variations) to no avail:

```
avgdf_final.interpolate(limit_direction='backward')
```

Every time, I get this result:

```
        day     lon     lat    rad
nums                              
0     319.0  56.485  2.7800  1.158
1     320.0  56.485  2.7800  1.158
2     321.0  56.485  2.7800  1.158
3     322.0  56.485  2.7800  1.158
4     323.0  43.300  2.6800  1.166
5     324.0  30.100  2.5775  1.174
```

Clearly, this isn't interpolated: it's just the same rows pasted in again. What can I do to make this work? Thanks in advance for any replies!!

Comment: This is what `bfill` does. What would be your (explicit) expected output?

Comment: I've also tried it with (method='linear',direction='backwards') and it did the same thing. I just want a linear fill in the backwards direction. I would expect row 2 to read something like 321    69     2.89    1.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolation with "linear" requires to be in between data, which is not the case here (you rather want to **extra**polate).

You could try to use a spline:

```
df2 = df.interpolate(method='spline', limit_direction='backward', order=1)
```

See the [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) documentation for other methods.

Output:

```
     day      lon       lat    rad
0  319.0  96.0650  3.084167  1.134
1  320.0  82.8725  2.982917  1.142
2  321.0  69.6800  2.881667  1.150
3  322.0  56.4850  2.780000  1.158
4  323.0  43.3000  2.680000  1.166
5  324.0  30.1000  2.577500  1.174
```